# How to show Erlang C function has decreasing differences?

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

**Erlang C** function is defined as
$$C(s,a) = \frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\frac{s!(1-a/s)}{k! a^{s-k}}+1}. $$

It is easy to show that $C(s,a)$ is increasing in $a$ and decreasing in $s$. We can also plot (by extending $s$ from integers to real values) the function (see below) and observe that $C$ has decreasing differences, i.e., for $a<a', s<s'$,
$$C(s,a')-C(s,a) > C(s',a')-C(s',a).$$

**Question**: how to prove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Just trying to "simplify" the problem.*

Write

$$C(s,a) = \frac{1}{F(s,a)+1}$$

$$F(s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\frac{s!\left(1-\frac{a}{s}\right)}{k!\, a^{s-k}}=(s-a) \,e^a \, E_{1-s}(a)$$

$$\frac{\partial C(s,a)}{\partial s}=-\frac 1 {\big(C(s,a)\big)^2}\,\frac{\partial F(s,a)}{\partial s}$$
$$\frac{\partial C(s,a)}{\partial a}=-\frac 1 {\big(C(s,a)\big)^2}\,\frac{\partial F(s,a)}{\partial a}$$

The problem is now to work the two required partial derivatives which are more than complicated ($\frac{\partial F(s,a)}{\partial s}$ involves generalized hypergeometric functions).